# Java8 stream with nested objects

Tags: java, java-8

So I'm new to Java8.  I've read about streams, but most examples are very basic.  I was wondering how it'd be done with nested objects.  Here is an example from my code:

```
for (Gas gas : gases) {
  resourceNodes.add(gas.getRefinery().unit());
}
```

It seems like I should be able to one-line this with a stream, but I can't quite figure it out.  Could someone provide an answer with a stream.  Is there a way to use :: syntax with nested methods too?

Edit:
To clarify the example, getRefinery() returns an object of type: UnitInPool, whose method unit() returns an object of type: Unit.  resourceNodes is an ArrayList of Unit.

Answer (score 3):

The `::` syntax that you refer to is what's known as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

---

Assuming `resourceNodes` is unassigned (or empty, in which case you can remove any previous assignment) prior to the for-loop, then you'd want to first [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) each `Gas` to whatever type `unit()` returns, and then [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html):

```
resourceNodes = gases.stream()
                     .map(Gas::getRefinery)
                     .map(GasRefinery::unit)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise, if your goal is to simply add to `resourceNodes`, then it would be very similar:

```
resourceNodes.addAll(gases.stream()
                          .map(Gas::getRefinery)
                          .map(GasRefinery::unit)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide more code for a reasonable answer, but I'm guessing you can get a stream of units, whetever these are (and whatever `getRefinery` returns) this way:

```
gases.stream().map(Gas::getRefinery).map(???::unit)
```

then you can for example collect the result with `collect(Collectors.toList())` and just call `resourceNodes.addAll` with the collected result as parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
resourceNodes = gases.stream().map(gas -> gas.getRefinery().unit()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only method references, you can use this:

```
gases.stream().map(Gas::getRefinery).map(UnitInPool::unit).map(resourceNodes::add);
or
gases.stream().map(Gas::getRefinery).map(UnitInPool::unit).forEach(resourceNodes::add);
```

Otherwise, a lambda would likely be better since it's a lot shorter and more readable, and works, when you have methods that take multiple parameters or need to do multiple complex operations.

```
gases.stream().forEach(g -> resourceNodes.add(g.getRefinery().unit()));
```

This is basically the same as your previous code, but I would suggest the for-loop.

Comment: The last `map` will only work assuming `resourceNodes::add` is not a `void` returning method. Which is a reasonable assumption, as it *probably* is a `java.util.List`, but still. Even if it is a non-void method, mapping as means of just adding elements to an external collection smells hacky.

Comment: @pafauk. You're right, but other answers have assumed the same. Also, if I used a `forEach` there, it'd have been copying the answer Andy Turner originally posted. I'll change that though

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the SO community. I hope the following helps.

```
List<Unit> resourceNodes = gases.stream() // open a stream
.map(gas -> gas.getRefinery()) // convert to UnitInPool
.filter(unitInPool -> Objects.nonNull(unitInPool)) // null check to avoid NPE
.map(unip -> unip.getUnit()) // convert to Unit
.collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect all the values in a List
```